# The routes of Webapck server Can not get /page

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I used the webpack dev server to run the local web server.

When I used browser enter the url `/localhost:8080/sign_in` and I got the error.

> Can not get /sign_in

I add a Object `historyApiFallback: true` in my `webpack.config.js` and it was solved.

```
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    headers:{
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    }
  }
```

But when I compiled `webpack -p` and run the `node server.js` the same error was happened again.

followed `server.js` code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html')
const publicPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))

app.use(publicPath)
app.use(history())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(indexPath));
} );



app.listen(port);
```

How can I fixed it?

Comment: You only defined the path `/`. You would need to add `/sign_in` too.

Comment: @Seblor I used react-routes in my app, so every page was depended /index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined your route for sign-in.

```
app.get('/sign-in', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(   PATH   ));
} );
```

since server side rendering is not active, you cannot go directly to sign-in. You will have to go to index and click on link so react-router can go to that path

Comment: How can I set all route was dependency the `index.html` just like rails setted routes `get '*path', to: 'home#index'`?

Comment: `app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(indexPath));
} );`
this will make all routes to go to index